# Webdav for Xpages and Domino only works giving anonymous full access rights

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, webdav

I have installed webdav for Domino and made the required changes in the webdavconfig.nsf.

If I give designer rights to anonymous users,  I can access and update the word documuments in the database through Internet Explorer and MS Word, but if I change them back to no rights, i cant. Of course I want to edit them with my own credentials.

What am I doing wrong?

OS windows 10

URL which works anonymous (????? are hidden)

webdavs://dev.?????.nl/webdav/domino/eod.docx

https://dev.?????.nl/development/webdab.nsf

https://dev.?????.nl/webdav/domino/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you configure SSO with your Domino?

Comment: I am going to, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote that application.

You are in the tricky land of authentication. Domino supports: Basic, FormBased, Cookie based (LTPA) SPENEGO and SAML. The later 3 need configuration work.

What happens when you use WebDAV is that no longer your browser, but a local library (belonging to Explorer or Office) talks to Domino.
You can "manually" try that using File - Open and paste the URL to the document (the one with `https://`, not `webdavs://`).

The only thing that happens with a `webdavs://` url: a little helper checks, based on extension in the registry, what app is needed (Word, Excel, OpenOffice) and then calls that app with the `https://` url as parameter. Like starting e.g. Excel from the command line:

`excel.exe https://someserver/path/spreadshit.xls`

By default Windows now uses NTLM or Kerberos authentication, neither of them supported by Domino (There used to be a proxy translating NTML to LTPA by a 3rd party). So no credential reaches Domino. Hence you need anonymous access rights.

For older versions of Windows [I described what you need to do](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2011/06/it-isnt-a-standard-if-it-isnt-broken-today-webdav.html) to get Basic Auth going.

Never came around to check what setting you would need on Windows 8 or 10 to allow basic auth there. Also, in theory, SAML or SPENEGO SSO might do the trick.

If you got Mac or Linux, you could [check them first](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2013/03/round-trip-editing-experience-in-web-browsers.html).

So the challenge isn't with the webDAV plugin as such, but in finding a common authentication ground between the OS and Domino. Hope that clarifies it a little.

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for your response. I was afraid this would be the answer. I will look into SAML or SPENEGO SSO to find out if it will indeed do the trick. If we get it to work, I will inform you and show how it can be done.   Kind regards, René

Comment: > Hence you need anonymous access rights. That's odd, I run WebDAV in database with Anonymous=No Access. That's why I asked about SSO, our server is configured to use LTPA.

Comment: @stwissel  those the authentication problem produce the following error as well? "Error saving the document..: The object cannot be created in directory. "http:// localhost/webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC‌​1258018004E4710‌​/doc.‌​odt" http://i.stack.imgur.com/RS2hY.jpg

Comment: @simonpeter : easy to test. Open the ACL and see if the problem goes away. Note: in my original code I never got to the point of implementing ADD new files, only EDIT

Comment: the error still remain the same, i am tryin to edit an openoffice document as well any idea what i could look out for